# htaccess redirect https to http and .com to .co.uk and http://www. to http://

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have a .htaccess file set up to redirect any of the following:

```
http://mydomain.com

http://www.mydomain.com

http://mydomain.co.uk
```

to:

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk
```

The code in the .htaccess is shown below (I realise the first line is nothing to with the redirect. I've left it in to show the code exactly as it is).

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /data01/xxxxx/public_html/php.ini 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code works perfectly, but now the client has thrown another variable into the mix. They also want to redirect the following:

```
https://
```

to

```
http://
```

I'm not sure how to implement this. I've searched for similar examples, but can't find an example that combines all the redirects that I need.

Hope this all makes sense! It's the first time I've posted a question, so I hope I've done it correctly.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have rule this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, I've tried your suggestion, but it's not redirecting for me. Tested in Google Chrome and it shows "SSL Connection Error" message. Also tested and failed in Firefox and Safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: `SSL Connection Error` has nothing to do with this rewrite rule. You need to make sure your SSL is setup correctly and has same DocumentRoot as the non-SSL one.

Comment: SSL is not set up for this site, which is why is why I've been asked to set up the redirect from HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: If SSL is not setup then obviously server won't serve any request starting with `https://` rule can't change that.

Comment: Ok. That saves me waisting time on trying to implement a redirect.

Comment: ok glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.